# \makeglossaries not working

Tags: glossaries, makeindex

I have a problem with the package glossaries. I am trying to generate a glossary list (\newacronym...) but TeXnicCenter does not print it in the final document. It says that entries have been read and writen in the output file .gls but the pdf document does not include it.

MakeIndex has been configured as follows: "%tm.acn" -s   "%tm.ist" -o "%tm.gls"

My main file contains the document definitions but I have all setting in a new TeX document which is "called" by the main file.

[image]
[image]
Thanks you in advance!

---

Additional information about the Build Output Messages:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please post code as text rather than images.so it can be copied and compiled readily.  Similarly if you can distill your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) i.e. with no unnecessary packages, no `\input` or `\include` commands but just the minimum code required to replicate your problem that makes it easier for us to see what is wrong and offer assistance.

Comment: it works, thanks you very much. The problem was the .gls file. I have change the extension to .acr and everything is fine now. THANKS YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the makeindex output for acronyms goes to a .acr file, not a .gls file. The latter one is for "other" glossary entries. So use "%tm.acn" -s "%tm.ist" -o "%tm.acr". Or even better, use the makeglossaries perl script if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the best results by running a batch file after using MiKTeX.  Within the `file_name.bat` file (created and saved in the plain text editor or your choice):

```
makeindex file_name.glo -s file_name.ist -t file_name.glg -o file_name.gls
makeindex file_name.acn -s file_name.ist -t file_name.alg -o file_name.acr
```

If you are only making a glossary and not using another file for acronyms, you can eliminate the second line.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since it doesn't address the issue the OP is having.

Comment: As @PietvanOostrum pointed out, the wrong file extensions are called out in the OP's attempt to use `\makeglossaries`.  Changing the request will correct the error.  Another option, as stated previously, is to run this set of files externally—and running `makeindex` via an external `batch file` accomplishes that goal without needing the pearl script.

Comment: If you don't want to use the Perl script, there's a Lua alternative `makeglossaries-lite.lua` which will find the extensions from the `.aux` file (and determine whether `makeindex` or `xindy` needs to be run).